# How do I find out which quantum depth image magick is using?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

Is there a flag I can pass at the command line to view the quantum depth that image magick was compiled with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to pass -version to convert and it will show you the quantum depth behind the version number:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.8.8-6 Q16 x86 2014-01-29 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

Answer (score 7):

Just for reference as Dirk's answer is already correct and accepted, there are other ways of getting at the quantum depth and quantum range:

## Get Quantum Depth, e.g. Q8, Q16

```
convert xc: -format "%q" info:
16
```

## Get Quantum Depth in a variable called "Q"

```
Q=$(convert xc: -format "%q" info:)
```

## Get Quantum Range, i.e. 255 for 8-bit IM builds, 65535 for 16-bit IM builds

```
convert xc: -format "%[fx:quantumrange]" info:
65535
```

## Get Quantum Range in a variable called "qrange"

```
qrange=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:quantumrange]" info:)
```

## Get Quantum Depth and Quantum Range in variables both in one go (bash only)

```
read Q qrange < <(convert xc: -format "%q %[fx:quantumrange]" info:)
```